# Find the electric field of light due to an LED

Tags: homework-and-exercises, visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields, power

This is a JEE mains question which neither me, nor any of my teachers can figure out. Help me here.

"A red LED emits light at 0.1 watt uniformly around it. The amplitude of the electric field of the light at a distance of 1m from the diode is ___."

The answer is 2.45 V/m, if the answer key is to be believed.

Welp!

Comment: Please note that Physics.StackExchange is *not* a homework help site. Please [see this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since both you and your teachers are stumped I will give some pointers.

Pointer 1 - light is an electromagnetic wave. The energy flow is given by the Poynting vector. In vacuum (or air) this is

$$\vec S = \vec E \times \vec H$$

Conveniently, for plane waves the time averaged Pointing vector is (see [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting_vector) )

$$\langle S \rangle = \frac12 \epsilon_0 c E^2$$

Pointer 2 - you have the total power; at a distance of 1 m, that power is spread over a surface of $4\pi \text{ m}^2$

Pointer 3 - they tell you this is a **red** LED. Do you *need* that information?